# Cassandra: Avoid disabling swap system wide?

Tags: cassandra

I have just started with Cassandra. I have installed on two Ubuntu 16.04 boxes (i7, 16gb RAM) in a development environment.

On startup I get the following warning:

> Cassandra server running in degraded mode. Is swap disabled?

I understand the reasons for this (i.e., performance deprecation).

However, disabling swap for these two boxes is not going to work in my dev environment.

I found an alternative [here](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849515122/4/ch04lvl1sec60/stopping-cassandra-from-using-swap-without-disabling-it-system-wide) (requiring JNA with Cassandra), but I think it is out of date.

Is there a current alternative to disabling swap system wide?

ALSO: At what kind of data throughput rates will performance deprecate? Can the issue be ignored in development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Cassandra nodes will work perfectly fine, unless it start to swap. To prevent this scenario, check your hea size settings, pay attention to off heap allocation if you enable it in your cassandra.yaml. Very importantly, pay close attention to any other services you run on your node. Custom agent? Monitoring agent? Spark workers? Make sure you dont overallocate memory overall.

Comment: thanks....Are you referring to Cassandra specific heap size, JVM heap size or other?

Comment: I am refering to the Cassandra jvm heap size which you can control with MAX_HEAP_SIZE and HEAP_NEWSIZE.